# My passport will expire a few months after I start travelling - problem?

Tags: planning, passports, regulations

My passport will expire a bit less than seven months after I start traveling - it expires in May 6 2013 and I am travelling on November 16 — will it still be valid?

There's about two months before my trip begins. Is it still ok to travel or must I renew my passport?

Comment: it depends on where you are traveling to. Each country has its own rules.

Comment: it depends where you go. Some countries like Canada (from my memories) allow most people to have a passport valid until the day after you leave the country but some other countries require 6 months

Comment: @Polly, could you edit the question to mention two more things so we can better answer it: 1) where you are going and 2) what passport do you hold (citizenship)?

Comment: All the times I've noticed anything about this for any country I've gone to, the rule has been that your passport must have at least six months validity. So while it's surely not going to cover every country it's definitely a fact to remember as a baseline.

Comment: Also how long are you travelling for?? If it's for a year, you obviously have problems, but if it's for 3 days, you wouldn't have any problems whatsoever...

Comment: Please provide where are you going. The answer varies, depends on the destination.

Answer (score 13):

The comments really pretty much say it all. Yes, your passport is valid. Your passport loses its validity on May 6 2013. 
However, many countries won't, at least on paper, accept travelers with a passport that is valid for less than 6 months.

Comment: It's more complicated than that: for example the US demands 6 month validity, but certain countries (including Canada) they exempt. Without knowing both countries involved, it's very hard to answer the question.

Comment: You're correct, and with the information the OP gave, the best answer is a generic one.

Comment: @KateGregory have you seen the exemption list? It's very long. I haven't counted, but I would guess that it comprises 80 to 90 percent of countries.